# How to add rotation event to an ember highchart graph?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, highcharts

In the highchart site, they have an example of a draggable scatter box in which you can do 3d rotation

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/3d-scatter-draggable/

I was able to create the 3d graph using `ember-highchart`, however I have yet to figure out how to add the event of rotation in ember. What is the best way to do something like that ?

here is my component containing `ember-highchart`

**threed-graph.hbs**

```
{{high-charts mode=mode chartOptions=chartOptions content=content}}
```

**threed-graph.js**

```
chartOptions: Ember.computed('array', function(){
    return  {

      chart: {
         renderTo: 'container',
         margin: 100,
         type: 'scatter',
         options3d: {
             enabled: true,
             alpha: 10,
             beta: 30,
             depth: 250,
             viewDistance: 5,
             fitToPlot: false,
             frame: {
                 bottom: { size: 1, color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.02)' },
                 back: { size: 1, color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.04)' },
                 side: { size: 1, color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.06)' }
             }
         }
     },
     title: {
         text: 'XYZ'
     },
     subtitle: {
         text: 'Click on point to find coordinates'
     },
     plotOptions: {
         scatter: {
             width: 10,
             height: 10,
             depth: 10
         }
     },
     yAxis: {
         min: -10,
         max: 10,
         title: null
     },
     xAxis: {
         min: -10,
         max: 10,
         gridLineWidth: 1
     },
     zAxis: {
         min: -10,
         max: 10,
         showFirstLabel: false
     },
     legend: {
         enabled: false
     },
     series: [{
         name: 'Reading',
         colorByPoint: true,
         data: this.get('array')
     }]

    }
  })
```

Comment: you can do it the same as done in ur fiddle, As i changed in ember, please have a look. https://ember-twiddle.com/dc25362e67d8c9e6493eba329662acc9?openFiles=styles.app.css%2Ctemplates.components.highchart-component.hbs

Comment: @prudviraju add this as an answer for others to see, do however mention that you did not use `ember-highcharts`. I will accept the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do like this by using Ember.$

Comment: https://ember-twiddle.com/dc25362e67d8c9e6493eba329662acc9?openFiles=styles.app.css%2Ctemplates.components.highchart-component.hbs